# On elliptic curves, $\sqrt{x^2-101y^2} ,\sqrt{x^2+101y^2}$, and their ilk

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

> **I. Elliptic curves**

Given integers $a,b,m_k$. Let,

$$x^2+a = m_1u_1^2\\x^2+b = m_1u_2^2\tag1$$

If there is a rational point $x_i$, then the pair (after a transformation) is birationally equivalent to an *elliptic curve*, call it $E_1$, and frequently has infinitely many rational points. Assume a second $m_2$,

$$x^2+a = m_2v_1^2\\x^2+b = m_2v_2^2\tag2$$

with a different rational point $x_j$, and yielding an elliptic curve $E_2$.

> **II. Question**

**Q1:** What is the relationship between $m_1,m_2$ given that ALL the rational points on $(1),(2)$ are on the single elliptic curve $E_3$,

$$(x^2+a)(x^2+b) = y^2\tag3$$

Or knowing the generators of $E_3$, ***can we predict what and how many square-free integer $m_k>1$ are permissible?***

> **III. Example**

For simplicity, assume the special case of $b = -a$ which makes $m_1=1$ as the *[congruent number problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CongruentNumber.html)*. Let $a=101$. For,

$$(x^2+a)(x^2-a) = y^2\tag4$$

two solutions are $x_1 = \frac{2015242462949760001961}{118171431852779451900}$, and $x_2 =\frac{2125141}{63050}$. As applied to,

$$x^2+101 = m_k u_1^2\\x^2-101 = m_k u_2^2\tag5$$

the point $x_1$ also solves $m_1 = 1$, while $x_2$ also solves $m_2 = 101$. ***(What other $m_k$ is permissible?)***

**Q2:** In general, if $(5)$ is rationally solvable for one integer $m_k$, does it imply finitely (or infinitely) many other square-free integer $m_k > 1$?

Comment: "... is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve, call it $E_1$, and generally has infinitely many rational points."  Really? Current perceived wisdom seems to be that unless your family has a section, then the probability that a random element in your family has infinitely many rational points (i.e., has positive rank) is 50%. So maybe "frequently" would be a better word than "generally".

Comment: @JoeSilverman: Wording changed as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: "the probability . . . is 50%" assuming the signs are $+1$ and $-1$ with equal frequency.  That's usually the case (though hard to prove, indeed often beyond current machinery), but there are families with constant sign.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Indeed there are such families. But since the OP didn't construct his family with an eye toward skewing the FE signs, it's likely that it's a 50-50 family (although, as you note, proving it might be hard or currently impossible).

Comment: The elliptic curve corresponding to (3) is $Y^2 = (X+a+b)(X^2-4ab)$. And possible $m_k$'s correspond to possible values of $X+a+b \bmod \mathbb{Q^*}^2$. So, the number of possible values for $m_k$ is closely related to the rank of $E(\mathbb{Q})$. In particular, there are only finitely many possible $m_k$'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible $m_k$, when assumed to be squarefree, must be divisors of the resultant of $x^2 + a$ and $x^2 + b$, which is $(a-b)^2$; so $m_k \mid a-b$. (Note that bot factors must be in the same square class; if a prime $p$ divides the squarefree representative of this class, then the binary forms $x^2 + a z^2$ and $x^2 + b z^2$ have a common root mod $p$.)

This is the usual argument used in 2-descent on elliptic curves or hyperelliptic Jaobians that one uses to show that the Selmer group
is contained in a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of the
relevant etale algebra modulo squares (the algebra here is just
${\mathbb Q} \times {\mathbb Q}$; we are looking at a 2-isogeny).

Put differently, you get a homomorpism
$E_3(\mathbb Q) \to {\mathbb Q}^\times/{\mathbb Q}^{\times 2}$
(taking one of the points at infinity as the origin)
whose image gives you the $m_k$ for which there are rational points
on the covering curves. To figure out *exactly* which $m_k$ occur
may be difficult, since this is essentially equivalent to determining
the Mordell-Weil group of $E_3$ (for which no method is known so
far that could be shown to work in all cases).

Comment: Thanks. I knew the squarefree $m_k$ had to have a relationship. So they divide $a-b$. For the special case $a=-b=p$ and prime $p$, then _possible_ (not actual) $m_k$ would be just $m_k = 1,2,p$ which, in general, answers my Q1 and Q2.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII ... and, a priori, $-1, -2, -p, 2p, -2p$. But of course, $x^2 + p$ is positive, so we can reduce to $1, 2, p, 2p$. By considering $x^4 - p^2 = y^2$ modulo powers of $p$ and powers of $2$, we can rule out $p$ and $2p$ if $p \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and we can rule out $2$ and $2p$ if $p \equiv \pm 3 \bmod 8$ (and there are possibly some more cases). This is basically computing the 2-isogeny Selmer group.

Comment: This related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968383/on-diophantine-equations-of-the-form-x4-n2y4-z2) might be of interest.